# Postgresql script slow performance with a large number of insert statements

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

We have an MS sql server script which does a performance test to test how fast a customer server is.

Its kind of a simple/daft simulation of how our product loads data in batch jobs, and generally it runs in about 11 seconds on a fast PC with SSD, about 8 seconds on a Ryzen server with NVME disks, and about 20-30 seconds on older (e.g. 2013) servers without SSD disks. We once had a customer put up a VM that took 39 seconds to run the script so we knew there was a problem with that VM, so its a very good script for determining relative server performance.

Recently I ported the script to postgres because we want to get away from mssql licensing fees, but the script takes about 35 minutes to run, so I'm wondering if there is **any basic configuration to postgres that I need to do or changes I should make to the script to make it a fair comparison?** I don't want to change the script logic since the whole point is that this is a simulation of how our product runs and we're not going to rewrite our product, I just want to do what I can to get the script running faster without changing the overall loop structure.

The postgres instance is installed on a fast Windows 10 PC with SSD disks, and the same script in sql server takes 10-11 seconds. Its a vanilla install and we don't know enough about postgres to optimize it.

The real question of course is - "is postgres really that slow?" if not, we should be able to do some tweaks to speed it up, and this will tell us whether it's feasible to port our product to support postgres.

Here's the script code. You might want to reduce the number loops if you want to run it:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS zx();
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE zx() LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$
    DECLARE startdate date; 
    enddate date;
    i INTEGER;
    j INTEGER;
    g1 VARCHAR(255);
    g2 VARCHAR(255);
    g3 VARCHAR(255);
    g4 VARCHAR(255);
    g5 VARCHAR(255);
    
BEGIN
    
    create table TestTable(id int DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('TestTable_seq') not NULL 
                           PRIMARY KEY, textfield1 varchar(255), textfield2 varchar(255), textfield3 varchar(255), textfield4 varchar(255), textfield5 varchar(255))
                           ;

    create table TestTableSub(id int DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('TestTableSub_seq') not null PRIMARY KEY, textfield1 varchar(255), textfield2 varchar(255), textfield3 varchar(255), textfield4 varchar(255), textfield5 varchar(255))
                           ;
    
    i := 0;
    while i < 1000 LOOP
    
        g1 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
        g2 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
        g3 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
        g4 := uuid_generate_v4 (); 
        g5 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
        
        insert into testtable(textfield1, textfield2, textfield3, textfield4, textfield5) values (g1, g2, g3, g4, g5);
    
        j := 0;
        
        while j < 1000 LOOP
    
            g1 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
            g2 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
            g3 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
            g4 := uuid_generate_v4 (); 
            g5 := uuid_generate_v4 ();
            insert into testtablesub(textfield1, textfield2, textfield3, textfield4, textfield5) values (g1, g2, g3, g4, g5);
            
            j := j + 1;
    
        END LOOP;

        COMMIT;
    
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
        
END;
$$


--drop table TestTable;
--drop table TestTableSub;
--drop sequence TestTable;
--drop sequence TestTableSub;

CALL zx();

-- SELECT Count(*) FROM TestTable;
-- SELECT Count(*) FROM TestTableSub;
-- drop table TestTable;
-- drop table TestTableSub;
```

If you're interested this is the same script in sql server which does take 11 seconds ish

```sql
dbcc dropcleanbuffers

CREATE DATABASE PerfTest ON  PRIMARY 

use PerfTest

set nocount on
declare @startdate datetime 
select @startdate = getdate()

create table TestTable(id int identity(1,1) not null, textfield1 nvarchar(255), textfield2 nvarchar(255), textfield3 nvarchar(255), textfield4 nvarchar(255), textfield5 nvarchar(255))
create table TestTableSub(id int identity(1,1) not null, textfield1 nvarchar(255), textfield2 nvarchar(255), textfield3 nvarchar(255), textfield4 nvarchar(255), textfield5 nvarchar(255))

begin tran

declare @i int
select @i = 0

while @i < 1000
begin

    declare @g1 nvarchar(255),@g2 nvarchar(255),@g3 nvarchar(255),@g4 nvarchar(255),@g5 nvarchar(255)
    select @g1 = newid(), @g2 = newid(), @g3 = newid(), @g4 = newid(), @g5 = newid()

    insert into testtable(textfield1, textfield2, textfield3, textfield4, textfield5) values (@g1, @g2, @g3, @g4, @g5)

    commit
    begin tran

    declare @j int
    select @j = 0
    while @j < 1000
    begin

        select @g1 = newid(), @g2 = newid(), @g3 = newid(), @g4 = newid(), @g5 = newid()
        insert into testtablesub(textfield1, textfield2, textfield3, textfield4, textfield5) values (@g1, @g2, @g3, @g4, @g5)
        
        select @j = @j + 1

    end

    select @i = @i + 1
end 

commit

declare @enddate datetime 
select @enddate = getdate()

select @@servername, db_name(), @startdate, @enddate, datediff(MILLISECOND, @startdate, @enddate)
select * from sysfiles

drop table TestTable
drop table TestTableSub

use master
Drop database PerfTest
```

Comment: FYI we also ported to mariadb and that ran in 19 seconds.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? The Windows implementation of `uuid_generate_v4()` is extremely slow. If you just want to generate random text, `md5(random()::text)` will be substantially faster. Or if you do want a UUID use `gen_random_uuid()` from the [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) extension (but why would you store a UUID in a `text` column?)

Comment: Ah thank you, will give that a try now.. we're simply storing it in a text column because this is a simulation, i.e. the real product does not do that

Comment: The whole concept of inserting rows in a loop is the wrong approach to begin with. Use `insert ... select .. from generate_series(1,1000)` - that will be much faster anyway than the extremely inefficient row-by-row processing

Comment: No - this is a simulation of an enterprise software product, in the real world program that it is simulating, the strings will be from external sources. If I remove that the program loses all similarity to what we are trying to simulate.

Comment: That is a really strange "enterprise software" that does inefficient row-by-row processing in loops

Comment: As I said its just a simulation. Lets not take this off topic.

Comment: That simulation makes no sense to me, it's not a realistic workload

Comment: ok so I was able to remove the huge amount of UUID generation and I ran the modified script on Sql - 7.4 seconds, MariaDB - 7.9 seconds, Postgresql - 11.3 seconds. So that's solved the main performance issue, but now I would invite further comments on how to tune postgres further to see if we can get that 11 seconds down to 7. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: You are not comparing Postgres to SQL Server, you are comparing the performance of the procedural language between the two. Unless your enterprise software is entirely implemented in procedural T-SQL doing inserts in a loop and that should be ported to PL/pgSQL that is simply not a realistic way of running a benchmark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220399/discussion-between-user2728841-and-a-horse-with-no-name).